# How do I save image URL in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have tried to save an image URL in a SQL database but `path.compain()` does not work and just the file name is saved in the database instead of all the path. Can anyone help me?

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file3 = Request.Files[2];
    if (Request.Files.Count > 2 &&
        file3.ContentLength > 0 &&
        (file3.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("JPEG") ||
        file3.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("PNG") ||
        file3.ContentType.ToUpper().Contains("GIF")))
    {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/advertimages/cars/mercedes"), Path.GetFileName(file3.FileName));
        file1.SaveAs(fileName);
        modelcar.Image3Url = fileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't show the code that actually saves it to the database. Please show that piece of code since that's the one you say has problems. The code you posted looks good.

Comment: @Icarus the code looks good if he wants to save the actual file path to the image... I don't see how that will help him use it as an imageUrl later on.

Comment: Have you checked the value of the `fileName` or you just have problems with values in database? @MikeSmithDev good point!

Comment: the problem not in the database .it is in filename value

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new FileInfo object from fileName

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
```

And then use fi.FullName();